# Kendo UI Numeric Textbox format binding

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I would like to bind the format of a Numeric textbox during the button click.
Format is not changed during button click. Please let me know where am i going wrong?.

http://dojo.telerik.com/IZIBO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/angular">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
  <div class="demo-section k-content wide" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <input class="iptextbox" name="Vehicle's Mass" kendo-numeric-text-box k-min="0" k-max="100000000" k-format={{formatss}} k-step="100" ng-model="selected"/>
      <button ng-click="toggleMKS()">MKS</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
      .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
          $scope.selected =50;
    $scope.formatss ="'# bar'";

     $scope.formatss ="'# sdfsdf'";


      $scope.toggleMKS = function() {
        alert($scope.formatss);
       $scope.formatss ="'# jjjjjjjjj'";
         alert($scope.formatss);

    };
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is helpful if you include your code in your question, as links may expire. Please have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Code is added for reference.

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble adding a format at all, even using k-format in the HTML.  Here's the original demo, just add k-format="{0:n0}" to it, and you'll see that it breaks.  I've tried all variations I can think of: http://dojo.telerik.com/UzUHe